# C++ template constructor for iterators

Tags: c++, stl

I want to create different types of containers, and I want to sort them with my *SortedContainer* class. (I don't want to use functions like std::sort() now).

```
std::deque<int> d; d.push_back(2); d.push_back(1);
SortedContainer<int> sc1(d.begin(), d.end());
```

In the *SortedContainer* class, I want to create a copy constructor, that handles the iterators of the containers (d.begin() and d.end()).

But if I create another type of container of STL, I want to do the same.

```
std::vector<int> v; v.push_back(2); d.push_back(1);
SortedContainer<int> sc2(v.begin(), v.end());
```

In this case, I'm using std::vector instead of std::deque. So basically, it would be a template constructor.

```
template <class T>
class SortedContainer
{
   //...
public:
 SortedContainer(template_iterator begin, template_iterator end)
 {
   //...
 }
};
```

I know if I added *class template_iterator* as a template parameter, it would work well.

```
SortedContainer<int, std::deque::const_iterator> sc1(d.begin(), d.end());
```

But I don't want to tell the containers' type when instantiating the *SortedContainer* class. I want to find it out when passing *container.begin()* and *container.end()* to its constructor.

I have already tried using std::function and some other kind of methods, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding the template to the class you can make the function a template.

```
template <class T, class template_iterator>
class SortedContainer
{
   //...
public:
    SortedContainer(template_iterator begin, template_iterator end)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

Becomes

```
template <class T>
class SortedContainer
{
   //...
public:
    template <typename Iterator>
    SortedContainer(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

So now the function will except any type but you use the name `Iterator` to self document that the type is expected to be an iterator.  Do note that since this is a constructed SOP says that it should be constrained with SFINAE so it is not overly broad.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `make_sorted_container` function that does the deduction for you:

```
template <typename TContainer>
auto make_sorted_container(TContainer&& c)
{
    using element_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(c))>;
    using iterator_type = decltype(std::begin(c));

    return SortedContainer<element_type, iterator_type>(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto sv = make_sorted_container(v);

static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(sv), 
    SortedContainer<int, typename std::vector<int>::iterator>
>{});
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UAIo24jJQB0e709P)

---

In C++17, [class template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction) will allow template arguments to be deduced by constructors. In this case you need a *deduction guide*:

```
template <class T, class TItr>
class SortedContainer
{
   //...
public:
    SortedContainer(TItr b, TItr e)            
    {
        //...
    }
};

// Deduction guide:
template <class TItr>
SortedContainer(TItr b, TItr e)
    -> SortedContainer<std::decay_t<decltype(*b)>, TItr>;
```

Can be used like this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
SortedContainer sv(v.begin(), v.end());
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WKLDjKA6M64ukiwS)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the internal sorted representation of your sorted container *does not* depend on the type of the container used to initialize it. Then all you need to do is template the constructor:

```
template <typename Iter>
SortedContainer(Iter first, Iter last)
{
  //...
}
```